# Efficient functions over specific data.frame columns in a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of `data.frame`s. For example

```
set.seed(1)
my_list <- list()
ids = c("a","b","c","d","e")
for(i in 1:5){
  my_list[[i]] <- data.frame(id = ids, p = rnorm(length(ids)), m = rnorm(length(ids)), hp = runif(length(ids)), hm = runif(length(ids)), d = rnorm(length(ids)), a = rnorm(length(ids)))
}
```

What I want is to efficiently compute for each id (in the "id" column) the variance of the "p", "m", "d", and "a" columns over all data frames in the list. Ideally, this would return a `data.frame` like this (based on the values drawn above):

```
> result.df
  id     var_p     var_m      var_d     var_a
1  a 0.2371569 1.7810729 0.08264279 0.5074250
2  b 0.1091675 0.2107997 1.15051229 1.1578691
3  c 0.5385789 0.7650123 0.44215343 0.3137903
4  d 1.0174542 0.7818498 0.06414317 0.6079849
5  e 0.7343667 1.2870542 1.41615858 0.7362462
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `my_list`

```
library(plyr)
df = do.call(rbind, my_list)
out = ddply(df, .(id), colwise(var, c('p','m','d','a')))

#> out
#  id         p         m          d         a
#1  a 0.2371569 1.7810729 0.08264279 0.5074250
#2  b 0.1091675 0.2107997 1.15051229 1.1578691
#3  c 0.5385789 0.7650123 0.44215343 0.3137903
#4  d 1.0174542 0.7818498 0.06414317 0.6079849
#5  e 0.7343667 1.2870542 1.41615858 0.7362462
```

Or base R alternative, using the combination of `lapply` and `apply`

```
df = do.call(rbind, my_list)
df1 = do.call(rbind, 
      lapply(split(df, df$id), 
      function(x) apply(subset(x, select = c(p,m,d,a)), 2, var)))

out = transform(df1, id = row.names(df1))

#> out
#          p         m          d         a id
#a 0.2371569 1.7810729 0.08264279 0.5074250  a
#b 0.1091675 0.2107997 1.15051229 1.1578691  b
#c 0.5385789 0.7650123 0.44215343 0.3137903  c
#d 1.0174542 0.7818498 0.06414317 0.6079849  d
#e 0.7343667 1.2870542 1.41615858 0.7362462  e
```

Or using `doBy`

```
library(doBy)
df = do.call(rbind, my_list)
out = summaryBy( p + m + d + a ~ id , data = df, keep.names=TRUE, FUN = var)

#> out
#  id         p         m          d         a
#1  a 0.2371569 1.7810729 0.08264279 0.5074250
#2  b 0.1091675 0.2107997 1.15051229 1.1578691
#3  c 0.5385789 0.7650123 0.44215343 0.3137903
#4  d 1.0174542 0.7818498 0.06414317 0.6079849
#5  e 0.7343667 1.2870542 1.41615858 0.7362462
```

Or using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
df = do.call(rbind, my_list)
out = sqldf("select id, variance(p), variance(m), 
             variance(d), variance(a) from df group by id")

#> out
#  id variance(p) variance(m) variance(d) variance(a)
#1  a   0.2371569   1.7810729  0.08264279   0.5074250
#2  b   0.1091675   0.2107997  1.15051229   1.1578691
#3  c   0.5385789   0.7650123  0.44215343   0.3137903
#4  d   1.0174542   0.7818498  0.06414317   0.6079849
#5  e   0.7343667   1.2870542  1.41615858   0.7362462
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R approach

```
dat <- do.call(rbind,my_list)
aggregate( cbind(p,m,d,a) ~ id, var, data=dat)
```

which gives

```
  id         p         m          d         a
1  a 0.2371569 1.7810729 0.08264279 0.5074250
2  b 0.1091675 0.2107997 1.15051229 1.1578691
3  c 0.5385789 0.7650123 0.44215343 0.3137903
4  d 1.0174542 0.7818498 0.06414317 0.6079849
5  e 0.7343667 1.2870542 1.41615858 0.7362462
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(my_list)[, lapply(.SD, var), by = id, .SDcols = c("p","m","d","a")]
#    id         p         m          d         a
# 1:  a 0.2371569 1.7810729 0.08264279 0.5074250
# 2:  b 0.1091675 0.2107997 1.15051229 1.1578691
# 3:  c 0.5385789 0.7650123 0.44215343 0.3137903
# 4:  d 1.0174542 0.7818498 0.06414317 0.6079849
# 5:  e 0.7343667 1.2870542 1.41615858 0.7362462
```

Comment: You can chain the result to avoid intermediate assignment.. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Updated to use `bind_rows()` (more efficient than `do.call(rbind,...)` per @hadley suggestion)

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- bind_rows(dat)[,c("id","p","m","d","a")]
dat %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_each(funs(var))

#   id         p         m          d         a
# 1  a 0.2371569 1.7810729 0.08264279 0.5074250
# 2  b 0.1091675 0.2107997 1.15051229 1.1578691
# 3  c 0.5385789 0.7650123 0.44215343 0.3137903
# 4  d 1.0174542 0.7818498 0.06414317 0.6079849
# 5  e 0.7343667 1.2870542 1.41615858 0.7362462
```

Comment: `bind_rows()` would be more efficient